# to check the convergence of a iterative function

Tags: numerical-methods

[image]

In the above question how should we choose alpha so that the convergence of the iteration formula is the fastest?

Comment: for $x_0 \approx 1.4655712318767680267$ and $\alpha \not = -1$ ,they all converges after one step :} , you need to give $x_0$, or we could choose it , or what ?

Comment: Duplicate of https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2436000/find-alpha-such-that-it-ensures-the-fastest-possible-convergence-of-the-given-it

Comment: You can choose it

Comment: a partial answer is not enough, it must be answered for $\alpha$ and $x_0$ even hamilitonnien see more ...

Answer (score 0):

Case : $\alpha \geq 1$ and $x_0\geq 1$ so $x_k \geq 1$.

$f(x)=\frac{\alpha x+x^{-2}+1 }{\alpha + 1}$ give $f'(x)=\frac{\alpha -2/x^3}{1+\alpha}$ so $M_\alpha=\sup\limits_{x \geq 1}(|f'(x)|)=\frac{\alpha}{1+\alpha}<1$

and $f([1,\infty[)\subset [1,\infty[$ so $f$ is contraction, and iterative is fast when $M_\alpha$ is small, for a small $\alpha=1$.

Comment: I can't understand why you took only one case... And where in your answer is the value of alpha..please comment

Comment: And how small is the alpha

Comment: I can't understand why you took only one case.

Comment: a partial answer (which can be completed) is better than no answer at all, I suppose

Comment: I don't follow your answer and iam not convinced either

Comment: step by step : what about $f([1,\infty[)\subset [1,\infty[$, do you agree  with that (in this case) ?

Comment: I did a part of the work, so I want some of the reward

Comment: A partial answer to a partial question - seems fair to me.